# Request parameters are not transmitted on a POST request

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, post, webmethod

I invoke a `WebMethod` via Fiddler, I provide 2 needed parameters in "request body" and I get a strange behavior:

- first 10 requests, it works as expected => I can find parameters values in `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form`
- starting with 11th POST request, the POST parameters are not transmitted to `WCF` service => while debugging the `WebMethod`, `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form` is empty.

**Any clue why this happens?**

Here is my code:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/getsomething")]
[FaultContract(typeof(ResponseMessageStatus))]
[DynamicResponseType]
public Stream GetSomething()
{
    var par1 = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["myparameter"] ;
    //after 10 requests, HttpContext.Current.Request.Form is empty.
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you add some more details such as a screenshot of your POST request? Thanks.

Comment: @SilverlightFox: I cannot post it as there are too many confidential data. As long it works in same cases => data is valide. Something else is causing the problem, maybe something in the WS application (recycling or similar).

Comment: Is the information cache-able or is new information being returned each time? 

Are you able to change the c# request to update a counter? ( this would perhaps not clear the data out)

Comment: @Gauthier: yes, the data is already cached on C# side. You mean to send a new POST parameter (something like a timestamp)?

Comment: Yes that would be my first step. I'm not sure of how you implemented things or quite how c# implements its Contracts, so that might not even be possible.

Comment: Please check if `HttpContext.Current.Session` is present, sometimes some error even recycles AppPool itself & thus `Httpcontext.Current`.<..> might get destroyed. If it is so check for any error using logging.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have here typical IIS default 10 concurrent connections.
Are you able to verify then connection is closed after you call your WCF method from fiddler? Probably it is not closed, and when you hit 11th request it hangs (until any connection from pool is closed), so you don't see your data...

Solutions:
1.close connection (make your own proxy test client and close connection on proxy after call)

```
var apiClient = CreateApiClient();
try
{
    apiClient.GetSomething();
    apiClient.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    LogHelper.Current.WriteToLog(LogHelper.LogFiles.MessageLog, ex);
    apiClient.Abort();
}
```

2.change config settings:

```
serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="10000" maxConcurrentSessions="10000" maxConcurrentInstances="10000"
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, point 1. is not applying as we're talking about Fiddler and for point 2, I have already in place maxconcurrentcalls = 20. I set it 1000, no result.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed just after I sent the parameters as JSON. Still don't get the real reason why it works with POST/JSON.